# Three rows of almost the same code behave differently

Tags: ms-access

I have three dropdown boxes on a Main_Form.  I will add the chosen content into three fields on the form, Form_Applications.

These three lines are added :

```
Form_Applications.Classification = Form_Main_Form.Combo43.Value  
Form_Applications.Countryname_Cluster = Form_Main_Form.Combo56.Value  
Form_Applications.Application = Form_Main_Form.Combo64.Value
```

The first two work perfectly but the last one gives error code 438!

I can enter in the immediate window :

```
Form_Applications.Classification = "what ever"  
Form_Applications.Countryname_Cluster = "what ever"
```

but not for the third line. Then, after enter, the `Object doesn't support this property or method` error appears.

I didn't expect this error as I do exactly the same as in the first two lines.
Can you please help or do you need more info ?

Answer (score 2):

In VBA `Application` is a special word and should not be used to address fields.

`FormName.Application` will return an object that points to the application instance that is running that form as opposed to an object within that form.

From the [Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221371%28v=office.11%29.aspx) object you can do all sorts of other things such as executing external programs and other application level stuff like saving files/

Rename your `Application` field to something else, perhaps `ApplicationCombo` and change your line of code to match the new name.  After doing this the code should execute as you expect.

Comment: Thanks Mokubai. So the name "Application" is reserved and may not be used as a fieldname ? Never expected this. Going to try this Monday , Thanks again !  Henk.

Answer (score 1):

Form_Applications.Application is referring to the application itself. It is not a field, so therefore it is not assignable (at least with a string).

You really haven't provided enough code to draw any real conclusions though. But looking at what you have posted, you definitely need to rethink your approach.

Comment: Form_Applications is the database and behind the dot are the fields in that database. So

Comment: Form_Applications is the database and behind the dot are the fields in that database. So .Classification is a field , .Countryname_Cluster is another.  .Application is the which does not work. The other 2 are working as expected.  These 3 fields should be filled with the values of the 3 dropdown-boxes as soon as one is entering something in one of the other fields.

Answer (score 0):

It's to say definitely but you are not doing the same. It looks like you are reading a ComboBox value the same (I will assume Combo64 is the same as 43 and 56) but my guess is that what you are assigning that value to is the problem:

```
Form_Applications.Application =
```

Application is not assignable. Is there another field you meant to use there?